# Confused with my do-while loop program

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I'm supposed to write code where I am to ask a student 3 test scores that are between 1 and 100, if it displays a number out that range, it should display invalid, otherwise, I would display the student's avg and letter grade. I'm having issues combining two programs in order to make this program work, these are the 2 parts:

Part 1:

```
char grade;
double Test_1,Test_2,Test_3,Avg;
cout<<"Please enter your three test scores";
cin>>Test_1>>Test_2>>Test_3;
Avg=((Test_1+Test_2+Test_3)/3.0);
if(Avg<65)
{
    grade= 'F';
}
else if(Avg<70)
{
    grade= 'D';
}
else if(Avg<80)
{
    grade= 'C';
}
else if(Avg<90)
{
    grade= 'B';
}
else
{
    grade='A';
}
```

Part 2:

```
//Program to compute and display the average and appropriate letter grade of     
3 test scores

#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double Test_1,Test_2,Test_3,ClassAvg1,ClassAvg2,ClassAvg3;
    int sumTest_1,sumTest_2,sumTest_3;
    int n;
    sumTest_1=0=sumTest_2=sumTest_3;
    const int totalSum=5.0;
    for(n=1;n<=5;n++)
    {
        do
        {
            cout<<"What are the three test scores for student #"<<n;
            cin>>Test_1>>Test_2>>Test_3;
        }
        while(Test_1<1||Test_1>100||Test_2<1||Test_2>100||Test_3<1||Test_3>100);
        {
            sumTest_1=sumTest_1+Test_1;
            sumTest_2=sumTest_2+Test_2;
            sumTest_3=sumTest_3+Test_3;
            ClassAvg1=sumTest_1/5.0;
            ClassAvg2=sumTest_2/5.0;
            ClassAvg3=sumTest_3/5.0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the issues?

Comment: From your syntax, it seems you have a misunderstanding of how to use do-while loops. The brackets after the `while( ... );` are doing nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The only wrong in your code is this line:

```
sumTest_1=0=sumTest_2=sumTest_3;
```

It should be:

```
sumTest_1=sumTest_2=sumTest_3=0;
```

Your do-while conditions are fine with the || operators, since the condition (Test_1<1 && Test_1>100) will always be fault and never get out of the loop. You cant have a number that is lower than 1 and bigger than 100 at the same time, can u?

Answer (score 0):

There is a wrong in the condition of the while loop. You have to use `&&` operator instead of `||` -

```
do{
   //your code
}while( (Test_1<1 || Test_1>100) && (Test_2<1 ||Test_2>100) && (Test_3<1 || Test_3>100) );
```

Comment: It's not possible for both in a pair to be true at the same time, `&&` makes absolutely no sense here.

Comment: How can `Test_1` be less than `1` and greater than `100` at the same time? The OP's while loop condition was just fine.